# PayPal JavaScript SDK with a PHP server?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working with PayPal Standard Payments for the first time, using the code from their [button generator](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart) on my "payNow" PHP page. I'm fairly new to PHP and JavaScript, but well-versed in C#/MSSQL. The code provided by PayPal is (with the addition of a little PHP to modify the URL):

```
<!-- paypal start -->

<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1.25rem;">
          <p>Appster - including updates</p>
          <select id="item-options"><option value="Annual" price="360.00">Annual - 360.00 GBP</option><option value="Monthly" price="30.00">Monthly - 30.00 GBP</option></select>
          <select style="visibility: hidden" id="quantitySelect"></select>
        </div>
      <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        $url = "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js";
        $url .= "?client-id=" . PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID;
        $url .= "&debug=true";
        $url .= "&commit=true";
        $url .= "&currency=GBP";
        $url .= "&locale=en_GB";
        echo '<script src="' . $url . '" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>' . PHP_EOL;
    ?>
    <!-- <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=GBP" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script> -->
    <script>
        function initPayPalButton() {
            var shipping = 0;
            var itemOptions = document.querySelector("#smart-button-container #item-options");
            var quantity = parseInt();
            var quantitySelect = document.querySelector("#smart-button-container #quantitySelect");
            
            if (!isNaN(quantity)) {
                quantitySelect.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            
            var orderDescription = 'Appster - including upgrades';
            if(orderDescription === '') {
                orderDescription = 'Item';
            }
            
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
        
      },
      createOrder:
      function(data, actions) {
        var selectedItemDescription = itemOptions.options[itemOptions.selectedIndex].value;
        var selectedItemPrice = parseFloat(itemOptions.options[itemOptions.selectedIndex].getAttribute("price"));
        var tax = (20 === 0 || false) ? 0 : (selectedItemPrice * (parseFloat(20)/100));
        if(quantitySelect.options.length > 0) {
          quantity = parseInt(quantitySelect.options[quantitySelect.selectedIndex].value);
        } else {
          quantity = 1;
        }

        tax *= quantity;
        tax = Math.round(tax * 100) / 100;
        var priceTotal = quantity * selectedItemPrice + parseFloat(shipping) + tax;
        priceTotal = Math.round(priceTotal * 100) / 100;
        var itemTotalValue = Math.round((selectedItemPrice * quantity) * 100) / 100;

        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            description: orderDescription,
            amount: {
              currency_code: 'GBP',
              value: priceTotal,
              breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                  currency_code: 'GBP',
                  value: itemTotalValue,
                },
                shipping: {
                  currency_code: 'GBP',
                  value: shipping,
                },
                tax_total: {
                  currency_code: 'GBP',
                  value: tax,
                }
              }
            },
            items: [{
              name: selectedItemDescription,
              unit_amount: {
                currency_code: 'GBP',
                value: selectedItemPrice,
              },
              quantity: quantity
            }]
          }]
        });
      },
    onApprove:
        function(data, actions)
        {
            return actions.order.capture().then
            (
                function(orderData)
                {
                    // Full available details
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

                    // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
                    const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    element.innerHTML = '';
                    element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

                    // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
                    actions.redirect('paymentReceived.php');
                    //var successfulPurchase = document.getElementById('successfulPurchase');
                    //successfulPurchase.style.display = 'table-row';
                }
            );
        },
    onError: 
        function(err)
        {
            alert("Payment Failed");
            console.log(err);
        },
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
  initPayPalButton();
    </script>
    
<!-- paypal end -->
```

On successful payment, I want to use JavaScript to use another PHP page (yet to be written) to update my back-end database with the fact that the user has bought something, by writing a row to a table. My guess is that the right way to do this is to write a RESTful API page to write the data, using a `POST` function. My questions are, do I call this in the `onApprove` function just before the `redirect` statement?  What happens in the API fails? How would you recommend handling that?

Comment: MySQL will return errors if there's any issues and you can design the code to not do anything if this occurs but error them out and ask they re-try. So nothing major should had been done that you can't undo if this happens...

Comment: As for payments, it's done through API so yes some REST required. However up to you how you want to set this up, but most keep this simple. You send paypal what it needs to know, it tells you if the request has been approved, or declined. If there's an error say paypal couldn't connect, you'll get a 404 error or something to just re-check when you got time... As for storing this data, you do nothing till it's approved 100%; then it's your job to track this on your end for further processing/etc if you need to provide a service for that item.

Comment: Thanks @blanknamefornow (brilliant name, by the way). I'm pretty new to this stuff, so checking that what I'm planning to do is along the right lines.

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `actions.order.create() / .capture()` to create and capture an order on the client side and only later send information to a server.  Change to a proper server side integration.

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should **return only JSON data (no HTML or text)**. Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

- *This point about only returning JSON data is important since sloppy php code might output other things, or you may be using the Checkout-PHP-SDK sample code which has extra print statements. Remove anything like that, and only output JSON! You can review the response body in your browser's Network tab.*

---

Pair your 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: It seems the paypal buttons used to mostly show examples using actions.order.create() and .capture().   Do you happen to know why most now point to doing the same thing server side?

Comment: Those functions are deprecated, do not use them for any new integration